# Django: request.user becomes AnonymousUser after POST

Tags: django, forms, post, request

I initially login after authenticate:

```
if request.method == 'POST':        
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
```

I can jump from view to view and check I am still logged in with that user (request.user).
However, after a form (class NameForm(forms.ModelForm)) POST, request.user becomes AnonymousUser! Any ideas?

```
def name(request, job_id, tc_name, last_build):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = NameForm(data=request.POST)
        ownership = request.POST.get('ownership', '')
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fail/%r/' % job.branch_id_id)
    else:
        form = NameForm(
        initial={
            'tc_name':tc_name,
            'failure':tc_fail.failure,
             ...
            }, 
        )

    return render(request, 'fail/name.html', {'form': form, 'job_id':job_id, 'branch_id':job.branch_id_id})
```

Comment: Can you explain what `data` doing there ? `NameForm(data=request.POST)`

Comment: This is to initialize the form after a POST. If I remove it, the situation still the same.

Comment: do login again? how can I do it? the request has now anonymous!

Comment: I got now Exception Value:  

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'!

Comment: I have it in views.py, in fact:

Comment: class NameForm(forms.Form):
    tc_name = forms.CharField(label='Test case', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '150'}))
    failure = forms.CharField(label='Failure', max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': '112'}))
    date = forms.DateTimeField(label='Date')

Comment: Hi Raja,

Thanks for your kindness.
You can find the code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqbflhg4kuk29lk/robotfail.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question `name` view contains POST method only but Looking into your actual code I found that `request.session.flush()` in the `Name` view.

And Can you tell what is this doing in the opening of the view. Removing this will solve your problem.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot.
That line was there to fix a error that previously was happening.
Curiously that doesn't happen now.
Solved!